# jOOQ fetched timestamp has no nanoseconds

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, sql-timestamp

In a postgres db, using jOOQ, when I fetch a row that has a column defined as

```
timestamp without time zone
```

when I do a select and I get the value (fetched by jOOQ into a `java.sql.Timestamp`), then I see that the nanoseconds are missing.

E.g., in the database I have:

```
2016-04-04 15:14:10.970048
```

but jOOQ returns a Timestamp with value

```
2016-04-04 15:14:10.0
```

This is a problem for further comparisons. How can I prevent this?

---

**UPDATE**
Upon request, I'll provide more details.

In Postgresql I have a type:

```
CREATE TYPE schema.my_type AS
(
  mt_page                  smallint,
  mt_active_from   timestamp without time zone,
);
```

I call a function, using the routines:

```
DSLContext dsl = ....

MyTypeRecord [] records = Routines.myRoutine(dsl.configuration);
```

Then, the Timestamp will not have no nanos

The function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shop.myRoutine(
  OUT my_types schema.my_type[]
  )
  RETURNS schema.my_type[] AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  BEGIN

          SELECT ARRAY(
            SELECT
                  ROW(a_id, a_timestamp)::schema.my_type
            FROM schema.article
          ) INTO my_types;
  END;
  RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
COST 1000;
```

Comment: Just selected `ctx.select(val(Timestamp.valueOf("2016-04-04 15:14:10.970048"))).fetch()` and got the right timestamp. What does your jOOQ code look like? Can you provide more info to help reproduce this issue?

Comment: @LukasEder updated. I hope helps

Comment: Oh, this is from an array of composite type. That changes everything :) Those are serialised as strings over JDBC. Quite possibly, something goes wrong there. Will investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in jOOQ: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5193

jOOQ internally implements a composite type deserialisation algorithm, as PostgreSQL's JDBC driver, unfortunately, doesn't implement `SQLData` and related API for out-of-the-box composite type support. The current implementation (jOOQ 3.7.3) parses timestamps without their fractional seconds part.

As a workaround, you could implement your own [data type binding](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) to work around this issue.

Comment: Will this bugfix be part of the next release?

Comment: @mat_boy: Yes, [already fixed](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/commit/edd0ed3b875d7c68c07ab80504ea75d7078a1b36)